# Types of computers

Tags: architecture, computer-science, history, theory, von-neumann

I have read somewhere recently something related to the kind of computers.

The reading was related to Lisp and Emacs that fit into an "architectural" model more like a Turing Machine.

In the other hand it was C and the "other" architectural model was named after someone whose name I don't remember, but named as the most successful type of computer because that's what we all use nowadays ( that is cpu + ram + hd + etc etc ).

What's the name of that type of computer if it is not a turing machine ( that afaik is an abstract model rather than a physical )

Byte!

Comment: I would say this *is* a programming question. It is more relevent than all those 'what is your favorite programming cartoon' questions IMO

Comment: It's possible that what you remember is the second paragraph of http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html , although it's different from what you say in the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're thinking of the [Von Neumann architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture). Though most modern computers use the Von Neumann architecture, there's also the similar [Harvard architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) that is still Turing-complete, but which separates the instructions being executed and the data being read and written to.

Comment: I make a living writing code for Harvard architecture 8051 based systems.  The 8051s are fairly modern, they run at up to 50 mips, support branch prediction and have read-ahead RAM cache.  IIRC, AVR and PICs are Harvard too.

So, I'd say "Most modern computers use Von Neumann architecture" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the [Von Neumann architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture)?

Comment: Haha, redundant by 37 seconds.